# Android: SP (scale independent pixels) doesn't seem to work, look really different on each device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I must been doing something wrong,

I have a layout xml and linear layout, this linear layout has 2 buttons (rather large) and the gravity is set to center on both the vertical and horizontal for the linear layout.. Looks great on the screen i designed for Nexus One 3.7"

So in eclipse i change the nexus one (usin the drop down) to a 10.1 screen and everything displays ok but my buttons are so small, they don't seem to keep there look and feel size..

Am i doing something wrong..

What i am trying to do is have my screen look pretty much the same in what ever device it is on - and i though the SP was the way to go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your buttons size determined?

Comment: Button size has the height and width set to 130sp

Comment: Isnt sp only for text, and dip for elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot to define `<uses-sdk>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you may see weird problems related to layout, etc.

So check your `AndroidManifest.xml` first to see if below example is defined or not:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5"
          android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

If the problem still exists, please post your resource xml so that the code can be checked.

Comment: Yes i have that in there already, mine set to min 14 and target 15.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had the same while switching between a galaxy tab and tab 10.1". Android classifies each screen into bins, and uses SP accordingly. Try run the following code on both screens:

```
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(dm);
Log.d("DISPLAYINFO", "Classified density: " + dm.densityDpi + ", scaled density: " + dm.scaledDensity + ", actual densities: x: " + dm.xdpi + ", y: " + dm.ydpi);
```

You may see that the smaller tablet is classified in a higher density bin, and so everything gets scaled up to try and look the same. It's a bit annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but in eclipse i have tried choosing, from the drop down, all the different devices and each and everyone seems to not scale right....  on the 10.1 the buttons are really small.. even on a 4.1 you see the difference...  Doing the above, what would that prove and help?  Is it a bug in eclipse or am i doing someting wrong.. I have no hdpi /higher density layouts or graphics or anything - i would assume that it should scale??  So are you saying i should switch over to dp rather than sp?

Comment: I've struggled with it a lot as well. I find that mm and pt tend to scale well, while px behave as expected. This flies in the face of everything we're told about multiple screen support, so perhaps you shouldn't listen to me. But trying out the above code would provide an explanation for the odd behaviour; I find both dp and sp to be quite unpredictable when you move between devices, because of the way their screen dpis are classified into bins.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the buttons are scaling to the right number of pixels, but when you switch to tablet view, the designer is scaling the image down to fit the 10.1" screen. If you click on the small icon on the top left of the designer, with the number 1 inside a circle, you will get to see how it looks when pixels are mapped 1:1

Scale Indepent Pixel (or Density Independent Pixel) is good for countering the effect of different screen (pixel) density. So, the comparison you are doing is not the correct one. To really see the effect if using DIP (or SIP), you should compare the look and feel of the layout on two screens with approx same physical size but a difference in screen density. (try two buttons, one with width specified as x px width and another with width x dp.

Further, if you are really looking to have button size based on physical size of screen, here is one way to do it. Instead of specifying the size in SIP, specify a "dimen" resource for that value. You can then specify a different dimen value for large screen and for small screen.

Example usage of dimen:
Specify the width as: 
`android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width"`

Then create a file res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="view_width">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Create another file res/values-large/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="view_width">20dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: An example would be great, I'm just reading this, and don't quite get your dimen thing :)

Comment: Wow Sameer, this is great info. Still a little confused, if i don't require to provide different dimens.xml then is there another way, for example every single app that i have scales up on my tablet from my phone. Although this does sometimes look ugly it scales up correctly. Is the only way to provide different dimensions? I would not be able to cover all screen sizes using dimensions.

Comment: Well, it would be best if you did not have to specify dimensions at all. That is you could specify all widths and heights using wrap_content or match_parent or by using layout_weights (when using  LinearLayout) But, if these are not sufficient to solve your problem, you may have to use the dimen resources.